# Why am I getting this error when I run "npm install" in termux while creating a react environment using vite on andriod

Tags: android, reactjs, npm, vite, termux

I've been trying to create a react app using vite but once I'm done with running this command:
npm create vite@latest

and I try to install npm

Using the "npm install" command it shows me this error :

npm ERR! Can't install npm globally as it will very likely break installation of global packages using npm. See https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/issues/13293

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.npm/_logs/2023-04-04T21_34_15_437Z-debug-0.log

I've tried using these commands :

npm install -g npm@9.6.3

npm install -g npm@9.2.0

and

npm install

Answer (score 0):

This is due to security restrictions in Android and Termux.
I suggest installing a local copy of npm in your Termux home directory. To do this, run the following commands in Termux:

```
cd ~
mkdir .npm-global
npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'
echo 'export PATH=$HOME/.npm-global/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

After that I was able to execute:

```
npm install npm
```